# Adding multiple markers on google map - not working

Tags: visualforce

The below is giving me an error:

> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

VisualForce:

```
<apex:page controller="clsMultipleMarker" sidebar="false">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageMessages rendered="true" id="msg"></apex:pageMessages>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 

            var map;
            function initMap() {
                var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
                map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
                    center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},
                    zoom: 8
                });
            }

            function showMarkers(){
                var addressArray = {!listOfAddresses};  // Use this format to fill addressArray 

                alert("say hello")
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
                    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map,
                                position: results[0].geometry.location
                            });

                            marker.setIcon({                                            // THIS CODE MAKES THE MARKER CIRCLE 
                                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                                scale: 5,
                                fillColor: " #FF0000",
                                fillOpacity:10,
                                strokeWeight: 0
                            })  
                            markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                            map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
                        } else {
                            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            function showActiveUsers(){

                //  alert("Please Select Your Location");

                var activeaddressArray = {!listOfActiveAddresses};   // Use this format to fill addressArray 
                alert(activeaddressArray);    


                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i = 0; i < activeaddressArray.length; i++) {
                    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': activeaddressArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map,
                                position: results[0].geometry.location
                            });

                            marker.setIcon({                                            // THIS CODE MAKES THE MARKER CIRCLE 
                                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                                scale: 5,
                                fillColor: "rgb(0,0,255)",
                                fillOpacity:10,
                                strokeWeight: 0
                            })  
                            markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                            map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
                        } else {

                            alert("Please click ok to continue");
                            //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }   

            function showInActiveUsers(){
                //  alert("Please Select Your Location");
                var inactiveaddressArray = {!listOfInActiveAddresses};  // Use this format to fill addressArray 
                alert(inactiveaddressArray);
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i = 0; i < inactiveaddressArray.length; i++) {
                    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': inactiveaddressArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map,
                                position: results[0].geometry.location
                            });

                            marker.setIcon({                                            // THIS CODE MAKES THE MARKER CIRCLE 
                                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                                scale: 5,
                                fillColor: "rgb(0,255,0)",
                                fillOpacity:10,
                                strokeWeight: 0
                            })  
                            markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                            map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
                        } else {
                            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            $(document).ready(function(){
                initMap();
            });

            </script>
            <style>
                #map {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size:12px;
                line-height:normal !important;
                height:500px;
                width: 800px;
                background:transparent;
                }
            </style>

            <div id="map"></div> 

            <apex:outputLabel >Enter Your Location</apex:outputLabel>

            <!--<apex:inputText value="{!ajay}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Get Location" action="{!GetAddressLocation}"/>-->

            <apex:selectList value="{!ajay}" multiselect="false" size="1">

                <apex:selectOptions value="{!lstSelectOption}"></apex:selectOptions>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!GetAddressLocation}"/>
            </apex:selectList>

            <input type="button" value="Show All Users" onclick="showMarkers();"/> 
            <input type="button" value="Show Active Users" onclick="showActiveUsers();"/> 
            <input type="button" value="Show InActive Users" onclick="showInActiveUsers();"/>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public class  clsMultipleMarker{

    public String ajay {get;set;}
    public List<String> listOfAddresses {get; set;}
    public List<String> listOfActiveAddresses {get; set;}
    public List<String> listOfInActiveAddresses {get; set;}
    public list<selectOption> lstSelectOption{get;set;}
    List<Student__c> lstStudent{set;get;}

    public clsMultipleMarker() {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Please Select Your Location Below'));

        listOfAddresses = new List<String>();
        listOfActiveAddresses = new List<String>();
        listOfInActiveAddresses = new List<String>();

        lstStudent = new List<Student__c>();
        //get All Location in Drop down
        lstSelectOption=new List<SelectOption>();

        List<Location__c> lstLocation=[select Id,name from Location__c];
        lstSelectOption.add(new SelectOption('','Select Location'));


        for(Location__c lc:lstLocation){
            lstSelectOption.add(new SelectOption(lc.Id,lc.Name));
        } 
    }  

    public pagereference GetAddressLocation(){

        listOfAddresses = new List<String>();

        /* List<Student__c> lstStudent=[select Apt_No__c,Street_Address__c, City__c, State__c,PostalCode__c, Country__c  from  Student__c where    Location__r.Name='Schaumburg'];    */


        List<Student__c> lstStudent=[select Apt_No__c,Street_Address__c, City__c, State__c,PostalCode__c, Country__c
                                     from  Student__c where City__c!=null and Location_Name__c =:ajay];   
        System.debug('size of students ============================>'+ lstStudent.size());
        System.debug('list of students ============================>'+ lstStudent);
        System.debug('keyword ============================>'+ ajay);
        if(lstStudent!=null && lstStudent.size()>0){
            for(Student__c acc:lstStudent){
                listOfAddresses.add('"'+acc.Street_Address__c+','+acc.City__c+','+acc.State__c+','+acc.PostalCode__c+','+acc.Country__c +'"');

            }
        }  

        List<Student__c> lstActiveStudent=[select id,Apt_No__c, Street_Address__c, City__c, State__c,PostalCode__c, Country__c  from  Student__c where City__c!=null and Status__c='Active' and Location__c=:ajay];

        if(lstActiveStudent!=null && lstActiveStudent.size()>0){
            for(Student__c acc:lstActiveStudent){
                listOfActiveAddresses .add('"'+acc.Street_Address__c+','+acc.City__c+','+acc.State__c+','+acc.PostalCode__c+','+acc.Country__c +'"');
                system.debug('active students');
                //and Location__c
                // and Location__r.Name =:keyword
            }

        }

        List<Student__c> lstInActiveStudent=[select Apt_No__c,Street_Address__c, City__c, State__c,PostalCode__c, Country__c  from  Student__c where City__c!=null and Status__c='Inactive' and Location__c=:ajay];

        if(lstInActiveStudent!=null && lstInActiveStudent.size()>0){
            for(Student__c acc:lstInActiveStudent){
                listOfInActiveAddresses.add('"'+acc.Street_Address__c+','+acc.City__c+','+acc.State__c+','+acc.PostalCode__c+','+acc.Country__c +'"');
                system.debug('active students');
                // and Location__r.Name =:keyword
            }
        }     

        return null;             
    } 

}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to clarify what you mean by "not working", including a **verbatim** error message if you have one.

Comment: Hi Ilya Lepesh,  I'm having total 250 records when i select my location from drop down list in vf page . but when i'm trying to plot those address   on google maps , i can plot only 15 records , please let me know where i'm wrong       Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting an **error message**? Please check in the console if it is not clear.

Comment: hi  Adrian Larson,  it is giving me the following error i.e Geocode was not successful for the following reason: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT on the vf page , but it is plotting me only the 10 records on the google map . and when i executed the  same soql query on developer console i got 250 records. please let me know where i'm wrong Thanks in advance

Comment: See, that's a super helpful error message. Please **[edit]** your post with the *complete* text.

Comment: Hi Adrian Larson, i have got many records in my student object with different locations, when i'm trying to plot the address of records on the google map for particular location , i'm not able to plot all the address  and when i tried to plot all the records for a particular location i'm getting the following  error i.e Geocode was not successful for the following reason: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT on the vf page and it is plotting only 10 records on the google map.please let me know where i'm wrong Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_mapMarker.htm) for the `<apex:mapMarker>` tag (emphasis mine):

> `position`
> `Object`
>
> Specifies the location of the marker. There are several ways to define the location:
>
> - A string representing an address. For example, "1 Market Street, San Francisco, CA". The address is automatically geocoded to determine its actual latitude and longitude.
> - A string representing a JSON object with latitude and longitude attributes that specify location coordinates. For example, "{latitude: 37.794, longitude: -122.395}".
> - An Apex map object of type `Map<String, Double>`, with latitude and longitude keys to specify location coordinates.
>
> **Note: You can have up to 10 geocoded address lookups per map.** Lookups for both the center attribute of the `<apex:map>` component and the position attribute of the `<apex:mapMarker>` component count against this limit. **To display more markers, provide position values that don't require geocoding. Locations that exceed the geocoding limit are skipped.**

Comment: Hi Adrian Larson , could you please let me know where i have to change my code .Thanks in advance.

Comment: @siva Wait...why aren't you using the built-in `<apex:map>` and `<apex:mapMarker>` tags...your question revolves solely around `Javascript` and has nothing to do with Salesforce.

Comment: Hi Adrian Larson , i'm very new to salesforce . So ,  i donno much about <apex:map> and <apex:mapMarker> tags . Could you help me in any way . Thanks in advance.